# Recover files from deduplicated volume in Windows Storage Server 2016

Tags: storage, windows-server-2016, data-recovery, deduplication, windows-storage-server

We have a Windows Storage Server 2016 having some volumes with Storage Deduplication enabled.

Its OS crashed so we had to re-install the OS (couldn't restore from backup).

There are some files which seem to be deduplicated before reinstall. When we open folders in such volumes, we are able to browse the contents of Folder (files show up correctly). But we're unable to read the content of files (unable to copy or open the files).

Question: How do we recover these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply do - there is no "recover". Besides you should have a backup - unless you forgot to install the deduplication feature, the OS knows how to handle the files. Now, if you were just forgetting to activate the deduplication feature, then you did not really "reinstall the OS". You partially reinstalled it.

Comment: Thanks, we indeed forgot to reinstall Deduplication role in a hurry.